# display object data name in the wiewport

Tags: 3d-view, data-blocks

Ewery time I want to check witch data block is used by the selected object I have to switch to object data tab in the properties view, is there a way to instantly display the used object data name somewhere to be allways visible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found is to create another propertis window with the object data tab opened.